# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kucoin'" but I have it installed and also tried reinstalling but same result. Running python 3.8.10

Tags: python, module, modulenotfounderror

```
import json
import os
import threading
from kucoin.client import Client

api_key = ""
api_secret = ""
passphrase = ""
client = Client(api_key, api_secret, passphrase)

def printit():
    threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
    pull = client.get_tick()
    cointType = pull[0]['coinType']
    print(coinType)

printit()
```

It says:
"  File "...", line 4, in 
from kucoin.client import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kucoin' "

Comment: Please add more information, for example, how did you install `kucoin`?

Answer (score 1):

you are using relative import, please check out the directory structure.
i suggest you to use absolute import, before running your script, run the command export PYTHONPATH=.

export PYTHONPATH=.
python my_module/**main**.py

clearly your script can not find the module you are using.